# query on database parallel or concurrent in with EF6 in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

Is there a way to query the database concurrently or in parallel so we don't get the

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext
```

error?

Pay attention that I mean queries that do not change the state of the database and only need to read information at a high speed.

i use `Task.WhenAll` and get above error!

this is a simple senario! i know i can pass `idList` to query with `contains` method! but if `idList` was grather than 200 query performance was bad! and throw exception.
i look for a valid and high-performance and scalable way for do this.

```cs
var queryTaskList = idList.Select(id => _getProductByIdAsync(id, cancellationToken)).ToList();
var queryResult = await Task.WhenAll(queryTaskList);
```

Comment: Just don't reuse the same dbcontext for multiple parallel queries.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many tasks are going to be created and this is dynamic. There are not many clean ways to create DbContext, and I can't think of many correct ways in terms of clean code

Comment: Creating an uncontrolled list of database connections introduces a risk of exhausting the pool

Comment: what is your suggestion? can you write your suggestion code?

Comment: Inject the service provider to your controller and then use it to further obtain fresh db contexts. It's clean. Then use the Data Flow or other ways of controlling your parallelized throughput.